# Use combineValidators for SelectInput to validate Guid.Empty

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, mobx-react, tsx

I am looking for a way to validate Select Input before submit final form in React App, I tried below but not working :
When I print the values in handle submit for each is : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
How can add the validation error when the Guid is empty

Added in the Final form file react .tsx :

```
const validate = combineValidators({
  projectId: isRequired("The project"),
  achievementStageId: isRequired("The project item achievement stage"),
  projectItemStatusId: isRequired("The project item status"),
});
```

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} loading={loading}>
                <Field
                  name="projectId"
                  placeholder="Select Project"
                  component={SelectInput}
                  options={projectsDdl}
                  multiple={true}
                />
                <Field
                  name="achievementStageId"
                  placeholder="Select Achievement Stage"
                  component={SelectInput}
                  options={achievementStagesDdl}
                  multiple={true}
                />
                <Field
                  name="projectItemStatusId"
                  placeholder="Select Project Item Status"
                  component={SelectInput}
                  options={projectItemStatusDdl}
                  multiple={true}
                />
```

projectsDdl, achievementStagesDdl, projectItemStatusDdl as array from APIs

And the component={SelectInput}

```
import React from "react";
import { FieldRenderProps } from "react-final-form";
import { FormFieldProps, Form, Label, Select } from "semantic-ui-react";

interface IProps extends FieldRenderProps<string, any>, FormFieldProps {}

const SelectInput: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  input,
  width,
  options,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
}) => {
  return (
    <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
      <Select
        value={input.value}
        onChange={(e, data) => input.onChange(data.value)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        options={options || []}
      />
      {touched && error && (
        <Label basic color="red">
          {error}
        </Label>
      )}
    </Form.Field>
  );
};

export default SelectInput;
```